# Property 'createAsync' does not exist on type 'TestBed'

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-rc5

I'm using angular2-cli to create projects and this spec file is automatically made by cli for one of my component. I upgraded my app to rc4 and since then I've been encountering this issue when I run this test file. Below is the spec file:

```
import {
inject, ComponentFixture, TestBed
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MockComponent } from './mock.component';

describe('Component: Mock', () => {
let builder: TestBed;

beforeEachProviders(() => [MockComponent]);
beforeEach(inject([TestComponentBuilder], function (tcb:  TestComponentBuilder) {
builder = tcb;
}));

 it('should inject the component', inject([MockComponent],
  (component: MockComponent) => {
expect(component).toBeTruthy();
}));

it('should create the component', inject([], () => {
return builder.createAsync(MockComponentTestController)
  .then((fixture: ComponentFixture<any>) => {
    let query = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MockComponent));
    expect(query).toBeTruthy();
    expect(query.componentInstance).toBeTruthy();
  });
}));
});

@Component({
selector: 'test',
template: `
<test></test>
`,
directives: [MockComponent]
})
class MockComponentTestController {
}
```

The above spec file throws an error on 'createAsync', I'm pretty sure that createAsync does not exist on TestBed but I replaced TestComponentBuilder with TestBed (TestComponentBuilder has been deprecated in rc4). Please provide suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `createComponent`:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
let comp = fixture.componentInstance;
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I understand that instead of using createAsync I should be using createComponent. But, where am I supposed to write 'comp = fixture.componentInstance'? It throws an error saying 'comp' is not defined.

Comment: I updated my answer. This is just an example how to get hold of the created component instance.